# Adding a record in Entity Framework 5 C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I'm a newbie using this kind of systems to manage a sql database, and I'm trying to insert a record and then query for it. I'm adding a record to the associative table beetween tables "type" and "origin", which are related "many to many".
The thing is if I use this code:

```
type _type_ = dataBase.type.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "photo");
dataBase.origin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "El Pais").type.Add(_type_);
var vari = from origin in dataBase.origin
           from type in origin.type
           select new
           {
               Origin = origin.name,
               Type = type.name
           };
foreach (var object in vari)
    Console.WriteLine(object.Origin + " - " + objeto.Type);
```

I don't get the new record I have just inserted.

But If I use "dataBase.SaveChanges()", just like this:

```
type _type_ = dataBase.type.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "photo");
dataBase.origin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "El Pais").type.Add(_type_);
dataBase.SaveChanges();
var vari = from origin in dataBase.origin
           from type in origin.type
           select new
           {
               Origin = origin.name,
               Type = type.name
           };
foreach (var object in vari)
    Console.WriteLine(object.Origin + " - " + objeto.Type);
```

It works!
I've read that .SaveChanges() "Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database"

So I'm confused: I thought that one advantage of using Entity Framework was that you wrote changes in that objected-oriented model, and you can make queries on it, which will result in a faster performance than accessing an on-disk database.

But from what I see, I have to "save all changes to the underlying database" each time I want to make changes to that model.

So... Where is the advantage then? How it works?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

this statement is not true:

"I thought that one advantage of using Entity Framework was that you wrote changes in that objected-oriented model, and you can make queries on it, which will result in a faster performance than accessing an on-disk database."

the advantages of EF are:

1. it relieves you of T-SQL, SPROC Management.
2. It relieves you of Data Modeling. (your Object Model can be used as Data Models)
3. It gives you unit testing ability for your Data Layer. (near to impossible if you use ADO.NET)
4. It actually makes your code agnostic of certain DB servers. (MS SQL, Oracle etc.)
5. All your code is first-class C#.. no magic SPROC names, inline SQL etc.
6. and more.. that would take a lot more space.

and if your aim is to insert records into the database, and query for it, then it is okay to do SaveChanges on it.. it ensures that the records are committed, and also assigns Primary Keys and other State Manager tracking settings to the entities.